# Flutter - Send headers with video player

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video

I'm trying to use `Flutter` [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin. But the API that the app uses requires a header for authorization.

After I looked up to the plugin's source, I found nothing about supporting the header in Flutter video player. Is there another way?

If not, how can I use an Android native plugin in flutter?

As far as I know Android itself supports this feature. Because I can't wait for the Flutter team to support this feature. My deadline is about to end.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Upvote this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16466

Comment: it's done! @Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone Who is currently looking for a viable http flutter video plugin a new and really good package has been created which supports http headers for video as well as many other Features. The name of the package is: https://pub.dev/packages/better_player/changelog . Hope you'll like it.

Comment: @Christian_X Does it support WEB and dynamic (separate) headers per `.aac` file with `HLS`?

Answer (score 0):

I put my token behind the video URL
You can try this authentication method

```
'$url?token=Bearer $token'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to do it that way in query params

Comment: This is a very bad solution, webservers may log the request url thus logging the user credentials. There's a reason why the token is usually in a header field.